# How to check the visibility of a div (javascript)

Tags: javascript, css, visibility

Html

```
<div id="greenn31"></div>
```

css

```
#greenn31{
    background-color:#093;
    float: left;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    margin-left: 544px;
    margin-top: 51px;
    position:absolute;
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

Javascript

```
if (!$("#greenn31").css('visibility') === 'hidden') {
               alert (source3);
               document.getElementById("greenn31").style.visibility = "visible";
               source3 = source3 - node31;
             }
```

How i could check the visibility of div green31?
Thanks for your interest!

Comment: Your code work fine check  https://jsfiddle.net/p7hk6wpo/1/.

Answer (score 1):

Your code work fine check the **[Example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p7hk6wpo/1/)**.

I'll just suggest to use `display` instead of `visibility` it's more efficient when you want to hide elements (see the difference below) then you could use jQuery function `is()` with selector `:visible`.

**`display`** attribute with `none` value will hide the element and hide also the space allocated for this element in the page.

**`visibility`** attribute with `hidden` will hide the element but space that is allocated for it still on the page.

Hope this helps.

---

```js
if ($("#greenn31").is(':visible')) {
  alert ("visible");
}else{
  alert ("hidden");
}
```

```css
#greenn31{
  background-color:#093;
  float: left;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  margin-left: 544px;
  margin-top: 51px;
  position:absolute;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="greenn31"></div>
```

Comment: "*it's more efficient when you want to hide elements*" It highly depends on your layout and the use case, both are as efficient, they just don't do the same thing.

Comment: What you mean by _they just don't do the same thing_? the both can be used for display/hidding purpose.. and you could find the one and only (difference) between them in the answer.

Comment: `Visibility: hidden` keeps the space occupied. `display: none` doesn't. So that's why they don't do the same.

Comment: They do the same thing (hidding element) with one difference (allocated space) and that exactly what you'll find in my post.

Answer (score 1):

If you're already mixing plain JS with jQuery, I would suggest switching to plain JS :)

```
var el = document.getElementById('greenn31');
var style = window.getComputedStyle(el);

if (style.visibility === 'hidden') {
    el.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zo2mbys4/

Comment: Nothing. But why do it with jQ if that's not needed in this case?

Comment: Why you think that this is the fully js he use?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below code:

```
if ($("#greenn31").css('visibility') === 'hidden') {
    $("#greenn31").css({'visibility': 'visible'});
 }
```